# Will a callback passed to the setInterval be fired even if the previos one didn't finish its work yet

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

Will a callback passed to the `setInterval` function be fired even if the previous one (fired by the same `setInterval`) didn't finish its work yet? If so, what can I do to workaround this behavior? Should I use my own boolean flag (like `inProcess`) or call `setTimeout` every time instead of `setInterval`?

Comment: Yes. If you need to wait for it to finish then you should use `setTimeout()` instead, and only call it when the work is done.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `setTimeout`.

I had similar problem and where I had to poll server for certain data every 3s till I receive data or a threshold is reached. I had written something like this:

```js
function getData(){
  $.post(url,data, function(res){
    if((res.error || res.data.length === 0) && pollCount < 20 ){
      initTimeout();
    }
    else{
      processData(res.data);
    }
  })
}

function initTimeout(){
  var delay = 3000;
  setTimeout(function(){ getData(); },delay)
}

initTimeout();
```

Benefit of this approach is,

- First, you do not have to make `interval/timeout` variable as global/in parent scope, so you can clear on success.
- Second, `initTimeout` can be made generic like

```js
function initTimeout(callback, delay) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback();
  }, delay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, the callback from your setInterval(..) is fired even some previous walkthroughs aren't finished yet. I think the inProcess-Flag is the most clean solution for you (even it's most understandable)